# Initialize (load) a java class with a java.lang.Class<T> instance

Tags: java, class, reflection, initialization

I have to admit that this is more a cosmetic issue, but the fact that I haven't found a more straight-forward solution makes me think I am probably missing something.

The thing is, my class (let's say Foo) has a very important `static` block where it registers itself (`Foo.class`) with a builder method in a `Map`, like this:

```
// somewhere in the class
static {
    Bar.registerBuilder(Foo.class, Foo::build);
}
```

This makes it possibe to get a `Foo` builder from the `Bar` class, a bit like this:

```
// somewhere in a method
Foo foo = Bar.getBuilder(Foo.class).apply("Hello World");
```

(if the builder takes a `String` argument). However, the upper code example will only work if the `Foo` class was already initialized. If not, this means the `static` block of `Foo` wasn't executed and the builder isn't registered in `Bar` by now, which is leading to `getBuilder()` returning `null` and `apply()` throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Thanks to the internet (mostly StackOverflow) I found out that you can imperatively with `Class.forName(String)`. But what really confuses me is that this method takes a `String` (therefore throws the checked `ClassNotFoundException`) and I haven't found a way to load and initialize a class directly via a `java.lang.Class` instance. I would have expected something like

```
Class<Foo> clazz = Foo.class;
clazz.load(); // does not exist
```

Instead I have to do this:

```
Class<Foo> clazz = Foo.class;
try {
    Class.forName(clazz.getName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException) {
    // handle an exception that is actually unreachable
}
```

I would like to know if I am completely missing something, or if not, if there is a cleaner way to load and initialize a class via the `java.lang.Class` representation.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

EDIT 1: As @Boris the Spider pointed out in the comments, `Foo.class` should probably already load and initialize the class, but it doesn't (in my case, at least) and that's why I even encountered this problem.

EDIT 2: Using the "complicated" way to load the class via `Class.forName()` (as in the code example) actually resolves the problem as I thought. It's just that I'd like to use a cleaner way if possible.

Using:

- Java 11 (openjdk 11.0.2)
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (2019.3)
- Maven (3.6.3)

Comment: @Boris the Spider Actually that was exactly my first thought about why there is no `java.lang.Class.load()`. But the thing is that I initially came to this issue because I tried to get the builder from `Bar` but I got the said `NullPointerException`. Apparently, `Foo.class` doesn't load `Foo` (or doesn't initialize it) in java 11 (openjdk11.0.2). Really confused me too but that's basically the root cause of my problem.

Comment: [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) takes care of this very scenario.

Comment: @BoristheSpider initialization is an entirely different thing than loading and as such, can only take place *after* loading, as it requires a loaded class. And while the time of class loading is intentionally unspecified, the time of initialization is [precisely specified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1). And no, using the literal `Foo.class` is not among this list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already referencing the class it would be much better to move that static code into normal static factory method. As why would you use reflections or try to reference some class just to make some code run when you can just run that method?

```
public static BuilderFunction createBuilder() {
    return Foo::build;
}
```

And just call it in static block of `Bar`:

```
registerBuilder(Foo.class, Foo.createBuilder());
```

If you need something more dynamic you can use service loaders, especially with java 9+ as they are much nicer now to use:

```
provides my.BuilderProvder with something.FooProvider;
```

And just load them all in Bar:

```
ServiceLoader<BuilderProvder> loader = ServiceLoader.load(BuilderProvder.class);
loader.stream()
      .forEach(provider -> registerBuilder(provider));
```

now even different modules not developed by you can provide own builders and you don't need to do any manual class loading (and class initialization is only guaranteed to happen if class is actually used, like some method or field used - note that constants are inlined at compilation so they don't count).

You can also use some hacky reflection libraries like ClassGraph or Reflections to get all classes of given type/with given annotation and then load them and invoke some init method on them all just like in my first proposed solution with `createBuilder`. This is how many components inside spring are registered, similar thing can be done with java annotation preprocessing to find this classes at compile time and just save the names. But if possible I would suggest sticking to existing build in solutions like service loaders.